# Java HTTPS Client

Tags: java, ssl, https

My question is how to request a HTTPS request to a Server, and get the content of response? without use any 3rd party API?

NOTE!! This is HTTPS, not HTTP!

For example, I give a URL:
"`www.google.com`" and port `443`, it can get the index.html from the server.

How to implement a such client? Could anybody give some example code?

I have written this, but it dosen't work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
public class HttpsClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  PrintStream out = System.out;

  // Getting the default SSL socket factory
  SSLSocketFactory f = 
     (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
  out.println("The default SSL socket factory class: "
     +f.getClass());
  try {
  // Getting the default SSL socket factory
     SSLSocket c =
       (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("www.google.com", 443);
     printSocketInfo(c);
     c.startHandshake();
     BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        c.getOutputStream()));
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        c.getInputStream()));
     w.write("GET / HTTP/1.0");
     w.newLine();
     w.newLine(); // end of HTTP request
     w.flush();
     String m = null;
     while ((m=r.readLine())!= null) {
        out.println(m);
     }
     w.close();
     r.close();
     c.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println(e.toString());
  }
```

}

Comment: Agree about this being a duplicate. Also, "it doesn't work" seems a little short describing the actual problem to me.

Comment: Are you sure there's a difference between using `https` and `http`?

Comment: sure. they invoke some ssl knowledge.